# How to share Sign-in session from android native app to my web url?

Tags: android, authentication, web, mobile

I have an Android native app that contains multiple web links for users to access. The expected behavior is when the user sign-in the mobile app, and a session is initiated. Then if the user clicks on the web link from the app, the web application will be open but without a sign-in prompt again. For the current situation, the user is required to sign in again for the new browser.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Earlier, I was using the below code to open the webview.

```
fun navigateToWebBrowser(context: Context, url: String) {
    try {
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
            .setToolbarColor(context.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
            .build()
            .launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(url))
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)))
    }
}
```

I just passed the token in the header and it works for me.

```
fun navigateToWebBrowser(context: Context, url: String, token: String? = null) {
    try {
        if (token != null) {
            val intent = CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build()

            val headers = Bundle()
            headers.putString("authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", token))
            intent.intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, headers)
            intent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(url))
        } 
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)))
    }
}
```